# Deserialize byte array in golang which was marshalled using python `marshal` library

Tags: python, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I want to deserialize a byte array into an object in golang. The serialization was done in Python code using the "marshal" library

```
import marshal

mpayload = marshal.dumps((key, payload, str(time.time())), 0)
```

I tried json.Unmarshal/gob.NewDecoder but it doesn't work.

I read the official documentation of Marshal Library which says "This is not a general "persistence" module" I understand marshal is internal to python but the serialization using marshal happened in legacy code which I cant change. Any solution ?"

I tried json.Unmarshal/gob.NewDecoder but it doesn't work.

Comment: python's `marshal` format is not `json`, so of course that doesn't work. It's a python specific serialisation format. You'll either have to find a package that someone has written that can unmarshal this python-specific format, or you'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: Right approach would be to de-serialise/un-marshal using python itself and store in a more general persistence  format

Comment: As stated, this does not work. The second sentence in `marshall`'s docs literally say "The format is specific to Python". Are you not able to use `json.dumps()`?